# How to create a script in rails and run it using console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to modify my database in rails for that I want to write a script that would modify my model accordingly when executed. I have no idea how to create a script and run it using rails console. Please somebody guide me.

Eg -: Suppose i want to write a script that has Model.all written in it and when I execute it using console Model.all should run

Answer (score 2):

Use Rails tasks instead:

## lib/tasks/mytasks.rake

```
namespace :mytasks do

    desc "This is a Hello world task. All it does it say hello"
    task :hello => :environment do
      puts "Hello!"
    end
end
```

Then in the console you do:

```
rake mytasks:hello
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it needs two corrections: (i) the filename must have the extension rake  ('mytasks.rake'), (ii) quotation mark after Hello! is missing.

Answer (score 0):

One the quick temporary solution adds a new class method to your Model:

```
class Model
  def self.modify_db
    Model.find_each do |item| 
    end
  end
end
```

In console just type: `Model.modify_db`

Comment: Yes this can be done, but is there another way... like writing code in some ruby file and execute it from console?

Comment: Yes, you can create a file in a lib folder. Define class or module and a function in it.

Comment: Too you can write a rake task and it in terminal

Comment: I was trying to do that only. In lib -> tasks -> hello.rake (                                        
  task :hello => [:environment] do
  Project.all
end )     , then in rails console I wrote rake hello.rake

Comment: Rake task need to run in a terminal, not  within rails console. `rake hello`

Comment: running rake hello gives me error Don't know how to build task 'hello'

Comment: Seems like you are looking for rake task